# laravel 8 on Docker Vite manifest not found at: ...\public\/build/manifest.json with

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, laravel-8, npm-install

i have problem to do npm run dev on docker on laravel project, i am using vue js authentication and i need to do npm run dev on docker and i need help

here is the content of my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine as node

WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . .

RUN npm install --global cross-env
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build`

EXPOSE 3000

VOLUME /var/www/node_modules
```

here is the content of my docker-compose.yml

```
node:
      build:
          context: .
          target: node
      volumes:
          - .:/usr/src
          - ./node_modules:/usr/src/node_modules
      command: npm run dev
      tty: true
```

how should i go about solving this problem npm install && npm run dev ?

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Are you able to `docker-compose exec` your node container, so you can get to the prompt inside that container? Inside that container, run `npm install` and `npm run dev` and check if any errors show up. Where is the package.json located, that you want to use for `npm install`?

Comment: I'm confused about your volume in your Dockerfile. It's `VOLUME /var/www/node_modules`, but in your docker-compose.yml you refer to it as `/usr/src/node_modules`? Also : double-check that line with `npm run build` in your Dockerfile: RUN npm run build`, see that extra backtick there?